# Youtube api Apache 2.0 license

Tags: android, youtube-api, google-play, android-youtube-api

In my Application, I'm using `YOUTUBE` `PLAYER` `API` and I want to upload my app to `Google Play`. `API YOUTUBE PLAYER` is under Apache 2.0 license, how do I have to write the credit in my application? I realized that all i need to do, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can place the open source licenses under your apps *Settings > About App > Open Source Licenses*, or something similar. This is what gmail does.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you for the beautiful answer. you mean just to add in about us screen this url content http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html i dont need to add credit to youtube or to the Author  ? if yes how ?